# Cannot import module from Powershell started from Start-Process

Tags: powershell, process

I have a powershell script: `MyPSScript.ps1`:

```
function DoFoo() {
  $Powershell = "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe"
  $Command = "& C:\Temp\myscript.ps1"
  Start-Process $Powershell -ArgumentList ("-noexit", "-noprofile", "-Command", $Command)
}
```

In `myscript.ps1` I have:

```
Import-Module "C:\Temp\myscript2.ps1"
DoSomething()
```

In `myscript2.ps1` I have:

```
function DoSomething() {
  Write-Output "Hello World"
}
```

The problem is that `myscript.ps1` is correctly executed, but the module is not imported as nothing is printed. Also, since I open the new powershell window using `-noexit`, I can type in it and if I try to call `DoSomething`, Powershell complains because it cannot find the command.

The funny thing is that, if I try to type manually the same import directive, then it imports the file corrently...

Are there any issues in importing a module from a Powershell which has been called from another process as I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the typo I fixed (missing "=") in your question, there are several problems in the script you provided. The first one (`MyPSScript.ps1`) defines a function DoFoo but never calls it. The second one (`myscript.ps1`) wrongly calls DoSometing() with parentheses. If you fix those two problems, you'll see your "Hello World".

**MyPSScript.ps1:**

```
function DoFoo() {
  $Powershell = "C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe"
  $Command = "& C:\Temp\myscript.ps1"
  Start-Process $Powershell -ArgumentList ("-noexit", "-noprofile", "-Command", $Command)
}

DoFoo
```

**myscript.ps1:**

```
Import-Module "C:\Temp\myscript2.ps1"
DoSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell modules have a .psm1 file extension.

Rename your file "myscript2.ps1" to "myscript2.psm1", then it should work.